# Ошибка "Нет модуля scipy" в PyCharm языка Python

Tags: python, pycharm

При прошлых запусках скрипта он выполнялся, но теперь жалуется на то, что нет модуля:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

На изображении видно, какой в проекте PyCharm стоит интерпретатор. Модуль `scipy` также установлен. С чем проблема может быть связана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: pip install scipy

Comment: Скорее всего вы установили `scipy` не в то окружение, которое у вас выбрано для вашего проекта. Обратите внимание, что у вас два окружения с питоном одной и той же версии. Окружение должно быть выбрано именно из того каталога окружения, средствами из которого вы устанавливали библиотеку.

Comment: @CrazyElf, при попытке установить ругается на старый установщик `pip`. Однако, видимо, по той же причине команда `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` не спасает. А как-то в PyCharm можно выбрать, куда ставить библиотеки? потому что там вижу успешную установку, но ничего в моем окружении не обновляется. Точно так же команда обновления версии pip сообщает, что уже все давно стоит. Но `scipy` снова ругается на низкую версию `pip`. И так по кругу

Comment: Ну вот вы же видите каталоги, которые написаны при выборе окружения в `PyCharm`? Выберите окружение, в которое хотите поставить библиотеку. Перейдите в соответствующий окружению каталог. Найдите, где там в подкаталогах лежит `pip3` и перейдите в этот подкаталог, скорее всего это будет подкаталог `Scripts`. И вот именно из него запускайте `./pip3 install scipy`, т.е. чтобы `pip3` запустился именно из этого каталога. Иначе он где-нибудь в путях может найтись и запуститься бог знает из какого окружения.

Comment: Кстати, ругань на старый `pip` - это скорее всего `warning`, а не `error`. Так что ошибка установки (если она вообще есть) вообще не в этом. Скорее всего вам пишет, что `scipy` уже стоит, просто не в том окружении. А про `pip` это предупреждение. Ну, кроме случая, когда вы `pip` умудритесь если из `Python 2.7` запустить.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо: в командной строке перешел на каталог моего виртуального окружения (в папку `Scripts`), в него командой `pip3 install scipy` загрузил библиотеку: все заработало

Comment: А, ну если у вас винда, то можно и без `./` перед командой. Просто в `Linux` например не так как в `Windows`, там запускаемая программа не ищется первым делом в текущем каталоге, а ищется в `PATH`, где найдётся первее, оттуда и запустится )  А в `Windows` текущий каталог - первый кандидат на запуск программы. Поэтому в `Linux` надо прямо указывать `./`, когда нужно из текущего каталога что-то запустить )